# Does implementing IEquatable methods break serialization?

Tags: c#

I have an object I can serialize to XML without a problem. However when I implement IEquatable and override the functions, I get an error about the XML not being generated correctly. Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to override Equals and GetHashCode.
See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IEquatable.aspx for more information.